# What does поджег бороду mean?

Tags: перевод, значения

I have to translate some texts from russian and I cannot find anything about ”поджег бороду”. I mean, I have found out that the basic translation is to burn one's beard, but I think that there is something more, like an expression/ idiom. The context is: "Я закричал, поджег бороду редактора и направился к выходу.
Вслед донеслось:.. "
Thanks!

Comment: This is joke, may not even be true. To maintain a conversation or create a playful atmosphere. It's easy. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not to "burn smb.'s beard" but to "set smb.'s beard on fire", a distinction that means rather a lot in practical terms. It's not an idiom, it's a comedic gag, with a touch of deadpan in juxtaposing it with the staid-sounding verb *направился*.

Comment: Could you please explain the connection to "направиться"? What does the latter mean besides "head toward"?

Comment: @SAH Nothing, it's not the meaning but the style and perhaps the pace that *направился* implies. I get the vague impression that he screamed, set the guy's beard on fire, and then "made his way towards the exit" in no particular hurry. Although now that I look at it, I could be overanalysing.